# ASP.NET MVC3, conflicts between Spring.Net MVC and other MVC Frameworks?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, spring-mvc, spring.net, telerik-mvc

I'm having trouble figuring out what the differences between ASP.NET MVC and Spring.Net MVC are. I understand how ASP.NET MVC and Spring.Net work separately, but I cannot quite sort out what the "MVC" part of "Spring.Net MVC" brings, overrides or changes in the way the ASP.NET MVC framework works/is used ; e.g. should I use "Spring.Net" or "Spring.Net MVC"?

In short, the question behind this is that I want to use ASP.NET MVC, Spring.Net and Telerik's MVC controls and want to be sure that using Spring.Net MVC would not prevent using Telerik's controls. Has anyone had some experience with this?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: There is a framework called `Spring MVC` for Java. Don't get confused there is no framework called `Spring.Net MVC`, however as @Marijn pointed out there is infrastructure support from the Spring.Net project for MVC 1-3 called `Spring.NET ASP.NET MVC`. Btw. we are running a enterprise app using MVC3, Spring.Net, NH and Telerik with great success.

Comment: Thanks both of you, I really mixed up `Spring MVC` and `Sring.Net ASP.NET MVC`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They don't conflict. Spring.net MVC adds dependency injection capabilities to asp.net MVC; [see details here](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/web-mvc3.html#web-mvc3-introduction), including specific web scopes. Many other DI containers supply modules that extend asp.net mvc this way.

Typically, this allows you to wire-up your controllers using the Spring.net DI container, as demonstrated [in the mvc 3 quickstart](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-net/blob/master/examples/Spring/Spring.Mvc3QuickStart/src/Spring.Mvc3QuickStart/Config/controllers.xml) (which ships with the examples). Or, more precise, Spring.net provides its own implementation of [`IDependencyResolver`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.idependencyresolver%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) to return `Controller`s, `ActionFilter`s and other services the asp.net mvc runtime requests.

Using Spring.NET MVC does not prevent you from using Telerik controls at all.